# Passing an optional parameter to a webservice in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, .net-2.0

Is there a way to pass an optional parameter to a webservice, instead of having to overload the method?

If the webservice user is accessing the webservice directly, I want to do ActionA, if the user is accessing the webservice through my web interface, I want to do ActionA + ActionB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't really have optional params for a service.

> Even if an input parameter for a Web
>   service method is optional, you must
>   still include it and set the parameter
>   value to null

[Supplying Web Service Method Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155386.aspx)

So, its optional to a degree, that you dont have to supply a value, but you're still going to have to write `null` instead. Overloading is the 'normal' way to do this.

Comment: The issue here is that the option param in question has nothing to do with the user and the values they are entering. The optional param is strictly to see what is the source (my web interface or did the client use the webservice directly). If I include the optional param in the webservice, it will show up on the webservice interface (which I don't want). - Thx

Comment: well, what you're looking to do there has little to do with webservices really. you're trying to audit the consumer of your webservice. there are far better ways to do this than an optional param.

Comment: what would be your suggestion?

Comment: you could use [web service authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996415.aspx), and have the user login to use the webservice,  and then the webservice can discover the caller's identity.